# Looping through an array in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, loops

Trying to loop through a sheets"data".Range"AM1:AS12" and copy the data to range beginning at BD1 as long as the data doesn't equal "#N/A"

My code works with copying the first column, but doesn't do anything with the data after that. Where am I going wrong?

```
Set S2 = Sheets("data").Range("AM:AM")
Set S3 = Sheets("data").Range("BD:BD")

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer 

j = 1
For i = 1 To 12 

   If S2.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "#N/A" Then 
      S3.Cells(j, 2).Value = S2.Cells(i, 1).Value 
      j = j + 1 
   End If

Next i
```

Comment: So I altered it to look for entries not equal to "". This code is now not skipping the blank entries and still won't go to the next column "AN" to pull more values.
`Set S2 = Sheets("data").Range("AM:AM")

Set S3 = Sheets("data").Range("BD:BD")


Dim i As Integer, j As Integer 

j = 1
For i = 1 To 12 

   If S2.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then 
      S3.Cells(j, 2).Value = S2.Cells(i, 1).Value 
      j = j + 1 
   End If

Next i`

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
<> "#N/A"
```

By:

```
Not(Application.WorksheetFunction.IfNa(...))
```

Comment: It still is not looping through the other columns though. How can that be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

This works when i tested it.

```
    Sub CopyCell()

    Set S2 = Sheets("data").Range("A:A")
    Set S3 = Sheets("data").Range("M:M")

    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

    For j = 1 To 2
    For i = 1 To 12

       If S2.Cells(i, j).Value <> "#N/A" Then
          S3.Cells(i, j).Value = S2.Cells(i, j).Value

       End If

    Next i
    Next j

    Call DeleteBlank

    End Sub



Sub DeleteBlank()

Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer

For y = 13 To 16 'Range numbers for the columns the data is copied to
For x = 1 To 10  ' Number of cells of data you want to loop through

If Cells(x, y).Value = "" Then
Cells(x, y).Delete Shift:=xlUp

End If

Next x
Next y

End Sub
```

Comment: You would need to set the for loop of j to the number of columns you want to cycle through and the for loop of i for the number of rows

Comment: So this does work for me in getting all the data over, but now it doesn't condense them. it essentially just looks like a copy/paste values but instead of the errors in the cells, they are just blank.

Comment: Thank you! It works great! I put multiple "Call"s to take care of multiple blank cells, but it is fantastic!

Comment: Mark it as correct if it worked for you. It might help someone else

Answer (score 0):

the best thing to is not to check if it is equal to "#N/A"
The best is to check if it is an error : If Not (IsError(S2.Cells(i, 1).Value)) Then